# How can I emboss a UIImage?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have UITableView with the cells having a image. Now I'm trying to make the image look like a UITabBarItem image when it is selected. I was going to follow this little tutorial to clip the images to a gradient. http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

I wanted to emboss the clip image to give it more life but haven't been able to find a simple explanation of how to do so with a UIImage.

I found this but I had a hard time understanding the process of embossing. http://javieralog.blogspot.com/2012/01/nice-emboss-effect-using-core-graphics.html

If I can get any help with or a lead it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the Core Graphics implementations and NYXImagesKit, I have an emboss filter in my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework. To emboss a UIImage, you can simply use the following code:

```
GPUImageEmbossFilter *embossFilter = [[GPUImageEmbossFilter alloc] init];
embossFilter.intensity = 2.0;
UIImage *embossedImage = [embossFilter imageByFilteringImage:inputImage];
```

Comment: Does your framework work with images with transparency? What I'm trying to accomplish it to make my images look like uitabbaritems. I have the gradient down but it missing depth to it.

Comment: @PhongLe - Yes, the emboss filter should respect the alpha channel of the source image, so if you have a UIImage with transparency, it should preserve that.

Comment: Cool, I am trying to add your framework to my project but I'm sort of lost when it says: "You'll also need to find the framework headers, so within your project's build settings set the Header Search Paths to the relative path from your application to the framework/ subdirectory within the GPUImage source directory."

Comment: @PhongLe - That always causes problems with static libraries like this. See the photos in this answer about another framework that requires something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260291/installing-core-plot-in-xcode-4-2-for-ios-project/10261140#10261140 . You can also look at how the Header Search Paths are set for the example applications I ship with the framework to see how this works.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed. The emboss with NYXImagesKit didn't work with transparency.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a method titled [Cocoa Touch - Adding texture with overlay view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083885/cocoa-touch-adding-texture-with-overlay-view/8090368#8090368). You might find that helpful. It does require that you have an overlay view in gray-scale that would generate the "emboss" look. If you know Photoshop or other image editing programs, you may be able to create an appropriate overlay to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time digging through google searches. I believe I found what I need.
This is a set of categories that allow you to manipulate UIImages easily.

http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2012/01/nyximagesutilities-nyximageskit/